# Sufficient condition for being a topological line

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $S\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ a (path-)connected subspace in the usual topology with the property that, for all $x\in S$, $S-\{x\}$ is disconnected and has two connected components.

Is $S$ homeomorphic to $R$ with the usual topology?

My attempts at (dis)proving this have been unfruitful, with the tools that I now have.

I kindly ask you to provide me with slight hints on how to tackle this problem.

*Note*: I'm not sure if path-connectedness is necessary or plain connectedness suffices for this result.

Comment: I think I'm onto something. I think I can define a total order in $S$.

Comment: The statement is wrong when talking about path-compoents. A counterexample is the [Warsaw circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape_theory_(mathematics)#Warsaw_circle). Notice however that connectedness is a stronger condition than path-connectedness.

Comment: How's Warsaw's circle a counterexample? Remove one point... It's still connected!

Comment: The Warsaw circle is a path-connected topological space. But if you remove a point, it has two path-components.

Comment: I ask for two plain connected components. Not path components.

Comment: Compare with https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-arc

Comment: Warsaw circle doesn't have this property even for path components - remove the upper left point and you only have one path component.

Comment: It is nearly the same as the question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/319870/homeomorphic-characterization-of-the-real-line). The second answer is pretty good.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Maybe you should post it as a community wiki answer here

Comment: @Jakobian: maybe... later...

Comment: Generally speaking, the ethos of the SE network is that each question should exist on one site.  Hence if a question might appeal to multiple communities, the author (or authors) should strive to find the community which is the *best* fit.  Alternatively, the author(s) might seek to expand a question to provoke answers which would be particular to a given community.  As this question seems to be substantially the same as https://mathoverflow.net/q/319870/ on MO, I am closing this version.